# Are NASDAQ open and close time consistent throughout the year?

Tags: nasdaq, timezone

The NASDAQ open trading time is 09:30 AM which currently is 13:30 UTC.

After DST is over does it stay the same? meaning does it become 14:30 UTC ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NASDAQ opens at 9:30 AM NY time.  I think of it as NY time instead of eastern standard time or eastern daylight time to avoid confusion for myself.

If it is 9:30 AM in New York, the market is opening

Comment: Yes, which is why the timezone is listed as `"America/New_York"`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9863625/478288) for a further explanation.

Comment: @chrisaycock Thank you for the additional link and info